# How To Create A Re-usable IBDesignable Code

Tags: swift, xcode, ibdesignable

When using IBDesignable, the following code is common and  I end up repeating every time I create a class, is there a way to avoid this repetition?

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    themeProp()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    themeProp()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

    themeProp()
}
```

This is how I am currently using IBDesignable to create styles for UIButton.

```
import UIKit

let colorWhite = colorLiteral(red: 0.9999127984, green: 1, blue: 0.9998814464, alpha: 1)
let colorLavender = colorLiteral(red: 0.6604440808, green: 0.5388858914, blue: 0.8827161193, alpha: 1)

@IBDesignable class PrimaryButtonA: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        themeProp()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        themeProp()
    }

    func themeProp() {
        setTitleColor(colorWhite, for:.normal)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        backgroundColor = colorLavender
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        themeProp()
    }
}


@IBDesignable class PrimaryButtonB: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        themeProp()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        themeProp()
    }

    func themeProp() {
        setTitleColor(colorWhite, for:.normal)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        themeProp()
    }
}
```

With my limited knowledge, I tried to create a function and tried calling it inside each class but it doesn't work.

It doesn't make any sense to repeat this 12 lines of code in every class declaration. So, if there is a way to avoid this repetition then please use my code for the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: The `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` is not needed. If only need that if there's some special configuration for IB. You frequently don't need that one (the `init` method is called, even when instantiated from IB). You certainly shouldn't be calling `themeProp` there. Generally `override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) { ... }` and `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { ... }` are sufficient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is **creating a common superclass** for these views. The only disadvantage is that you have to create a superclass for each type (`UIView`s, `UIButton`s etc.)

```
class DesignableView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {  
        super.init(frame: frame)  
        themeProp()  
    }  

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {  
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)  
        themeProp()  
    }  

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {  
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()  
        themeProp()  
    }

    func themeProp() { }
}
```

After that, make your designable class a subclass of `DesignableView`. You will only have to override `themeProp()` in that.

Comment: Can't we create a super class of `UIControl` to make it common for all the views like `UIView`, `UIButton` etc.?

Comment: @Hemang You could, but you’d soon find yourself constantly converting your view to another type, since it would be a `UIView` and not a `UIButton`.

Comment: You're right, in this case it's better to have separate classes if that matches the requirements and worth for the longterm growth of the app.

Comment: Thanks! Tamás Sengel. I tried your answer, it works perfectly.